# How to read from (redirected stdout) StreamReader without blocking?

Tags: c#, subprocess, streamreader

What I'm trying to do with C# is:

1. start a compiled C++ program as subprocess, read its redirected stdout.
2. output read bytes to another file, while stdout is appended by the subprocess.
3. kill the subprocess if it does not exit after 10 seconds.
4. kill the subprocess if it produces an output larger than 64MB.

I'm using a while loop for checking the execution time of the subprocess, but when I try to get output data from Process.StandardOutput the thread will be blocked and the timeout-checking loop won't work until the subprocess ends.

Is there any way to do a non-blocking reading on StreamReader, or workaround which has the same effect without using a non-blocking reading?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Process class to launch the C++ program ?

If so, you can [read asynchronously the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputDataReceived);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) with event.

Example from msdn:

```
private static int lineCount = 0;
private static StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

public static void Main()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        // Prepend line numbers to each line of the output.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            lineCount++;
            output.Append("\n[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
        }
    });

    process.Start();

    // Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process. 
    // This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm using Process. This works fine for what it is designed to, but two more problems: (1) How can I be notified or wait for the async reading exit? Will process.HasExited manage this? (2) This looks only works for reading lines, but the stdout may contain one line larger than 64MB.

Comment: Alright I found the answer of (1) in your given link... Forget about it...