# Send data with .bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file, tcp, udp

I got a c# project in which I start an application (.exe).

That Programm then executes a .bat file.

I need to get data from that script back to my c# - The data is a simple string.

I was thinking about sending it via TCP/IP or maybe with UDP. But I got zero bat
programming skills - and asked myself if that's even possible. Maybe some1 can tell me if its possible and maybe what's the best way to do that.

Maybe I don't even have to send it via IoT, when it's all on the same Computer anyway.

In conclusion I just want to send a string from a batch file to a c# project.

I searched a lot in the internet but I don't find anything.

Thanks
Leon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from (redirected stdout) StreamReader without blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861965/how-to-read-from-redirected-stdout-streamreader-without-blocking)

Comment: You can also write the string to a txt file with the echo command for the C# app to read. For example:

```echo Hello World> test.txt```

would write "Hello World" to a txt file called "test" in the same directory as the .bat was called from. Emager's link would likely be the better route to follow though as it doesn't require writing/reading from disk

Comment: Your post could use some clarity. Your program starts another program (using System.Diagnostics.Process) which executes a batch script? What does the batch script do? The following may be helpful: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: _I got zero bat programming skills_: Batch scripts have been around for quite a while. If you search for `batch script` using your favorite search engine, you'll find many results which will show you how to create one.

Answer (score 1):

*Your question isn't that clear so do you ask for help because; you can't output the result of a .bat process to your c# project?*

*If it's the problem you got, try to do;*

***+Your .bat file:***

```
(your_code/process) >output.txt
```

***+Your c# project:***

```
class ReadFromFile
{
    static void Main()
    {

        // Read the file as one string.
      // And set 'batouput' as variable

        string batouput = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Your_Path\output.txt");

        // Display the file contents to the console. Variable text is a string.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of output.txt = {0}", text);
      
      //or this line
      Console.WriteLine(batouput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly my problem. But I don't know when the batchfile is excecuted. So how do I get c# to wait. Or do I have to put a while around which waits for the string to be filled ?